# Method parameter that can take an object or a nil?

Tags: objective-c

How do I spell a method whose argument can either be an object of a certain type, or nil? You see those all the time in framework classes, but I've just encountered my first instance where it would be useful to create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pass nil instead of an object, there's nothing special you need to specify.

Comment: That's hilarious. I assumed I'd have to notify obj-c in triplicate, like so many other parts of the language. No wonder I couldn't find that documented anywhere!

Comment: The constant `nil` is defined as `(id)0` — so it is an object, and thus can be passed to most methods that take objects. (Some methods disallow nil, but *that* is the exception to the rule. For example, NSArray can't contain nil, so attempting to add nil to an array will create an exception.)

Comment: As a side-note, that's nothing to do with the way `-addObject:` or similar is declared; the implementation simply checks whether the object passed in is `nil` and if so throws an exception. Passing `nil` as a parameter to the method is – from the language perspective – still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void) myMethod:(Parameter *)aParameter {
  if (aParameter == nil) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
[anObject myMethod:foo];
```

Or:

```
[anObject myMethod:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, and an upvote for the code example. @kubi gets the check mark for beating you by less than a minute.